# Where to find type of edition in Salesforce org?

Tags: editions

one way to find the type of edition is looking on the title bar of the browser window. Is there any other way to find it out? though it is very basic question, but i need to know it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Click on **Your Name -> Setup -> Administration Setup**.
 Top of the loaded page you can see which edition you are using.
[image]. 

UPDATE
Removed the `WSDL` checking option to identifying the Salesforce edition based on @KeithC's comment. Checking at the **Administration Setup** is the best option to identify the edition.

Comment: FYI, I don't see the edition name in the Enterprise WSDL. (In the header comment there is information about the packages referenced including namespace and version.)

Comment: Agreed @KeithC. I think it's a misunderstanding the **Enterprise Web Services API Version xx.x** statement. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 5):

Once you have successfully logged onto SFDC ORG, the browser window/tab title (Salesforce.com -  will provide you with the edition like Developer, Enterprise, Unlimited, etc. you have logged in.

For Firefox (refer below)

[image]

For IE (refer below)
[image]

Comment: ... the questioner asked for a way other than this.

Comment: Sorry Keith... overlooked...

Comment: @Baskaran, you can issue the soql and find it . "SELECT OrganizationType FROM Organization"

Answer (score 0):

Go to quick search, type and navigate to **Company Information**.

Look for **Organization Edition**

Here you will find the edition you are using.

[image]